# Advantage Database ORM Tool or Code Generator Tool

Tags: nhibernate, orm, code-generation, advantage-database-server

Does anyone know if there are any ORM tools or Code Generation tools that work against an Advantage Database?

Comment: Telerik do one but its not free - http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what development environment you use.

For .net:

Microsoft [Entity.NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx)

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/)

Developer Express ([Express Persistent Objects](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/))

For Delphi:

I believe REM Objects has a framework that works with Advantage too.

Comment: I'm using C# in a Winforms application

Comment: Do you know of any free/open source projects. Unfortunately Subsonic does not work with ADS

Comment: If you want something free you already have the Entity.net framework in Visual Studio (assuming that's how you are using C#, as opposed to mono or some other IDE).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't give you much control over the generated classes. My client is getting persuaded by one of the ADS sales guys to use it over SQL Server but everyone I speak to has never heard of it, why is that if its so much better than MSSSQL (according to the sales guy!)

Comment: Different databases fit different business and technical needs (hence a ton of different database solutions).

Answer (score 1):

Probably yes, but you'll need to write a `NHibernate.Driver.IDriver` implementation.

Don't worry, it's easy. You can start from any of the most simple ones at https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Driver/

Also, you should write a `NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect` implementation, or you'll only be able to use the basic functionality provided by `GenericDialect`.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody posted [C# source for an Advantage Database NHibernate dialect/driver](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhibernate-development/s7HLs-aEXDk) to the nhibernate-development google group; you should be able to use this with any current ADS ADO.NET provider.

However, you should take note of [NH-3078](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3078) "TimeAsTimeSpanType issue when using Sybase Advantage Database", which doesn't seem to be fixed yet as of now.